# Radio Button not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Looking at some tutorials I have added the radio button but for some reasons it is not working. When i submit the form the values are not entered into the database

Here is my code
    case 'add':

```
    if( $_POST['addbtn'] == 'Save' )
        {    
            $name = '';
            if(isset($_REQUEST['name']))
            {
                $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
            }


            $imageName = '';
            $field = 'banner_images';

            if($_FILES[$field ]['error'] == 0)
            {
                if($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'] != '')
                {

                        $uploaddir =  "../inner_page_banner_images/";
                        $banner_images = $_FILES[$field]['name'];
                        $tag     = "";
                        $Twidth  = 980;
                        $Theight = 420;





                        @move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'],$uploaddir.$_FILES[$field]['name']);

                }



        $site = '';

            if(isset($_REQUEST['site']) == 'hino')
            {
                $site = $_REQUEST['checked'];
            }
            elseif(isset($_REQUEST['site']) == 'storm')
            {
                $site = $_REQUEST['checked'];
            }
            }



            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


            $Query  = "INSERT INTO inner_banner  SET ";

            $Query .= "name             = '".$name."',";
            $Query .= "banner_images    = '".$banner_images."'";
            $Query .= "site     = '".$site."'";
            //echo $Query; die();
            mysql_query($Query);


            $_SESSION['msg']    = " New banner image uploaded successfully ";
            @header("Location: inner_banner.php? module=inner_banner&action=view");
            die();
}


    include "add_banner.php";
    break;
```

My Html Code

```
<form method="post" name="frm1" id="frm1" action="" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this);" >
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" align="center" width="100%">


  <tr>
    <td width="18%">Banner Title</td>
    <td width="1%">:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"  size="40" value="" />
      &nbsp;<span class="required">*</span> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style=" background-color: #FFFFFF;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Banner Image </td>
    <td valign="top">:</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="banner_images"  id="banner_images" size="20"  />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style=" background-color: #FFFFFF;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td valign="top">Select:</td>
    <td valign="top">:</td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="hino" name="site" id="site"  />
          HINO
          <input type="radio" value="storm" name="site" id="site" />
          Storm

          &nbsp;<span class="required">*</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style=" background-color: #FFFFFF;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="addbtn" value="Save" />
      &nbsp;
      <input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick="document.location.href='inner_banner.php?module=inner_banner'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Validation" id="Validation" value="
        Field=name|Alias=Banner Title|Validate=BLANK^                            
        Field=banner_images|Alias=Banner Image|Validate=BLANK" />
```

can somebosy pls look into it why the values are not getting entered in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is missing a comma:

```
$Query .= "banner_images    = '".$banner_images."'";
```

should be

```
$Query .= "banner_images    = '".$banner_images."',";
```

As a sidenote, you are vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) with your code, you might want to use prepared statements or at least [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: thanks david I ll loolk into it, but rightnow I first want to make my radio button work which is not working, So can u pls help me in that

Comment: Wasn't that your question? Whats wrong with your radio buttons? If you have a missing comma in your sql statement, your query will fail - no matter what your radio buttons are or aren't doing ;).

Comment: Thanks a lotttttt david it worked for me. thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this:

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['site']) == 'hino')
    {
        $site = $_REQUEST['checked'];
    }
    elseif(isset($_REQUEST['site']) == 'storm')
    {
        $site = $_REQUEST['checked'];
    }
```

be:

```
        if(isset($_REQUEST['site']) == 'hino')
        {
            $site = $_REQUEST['site'];
        }
        elseif(isset($_REQUEST['site']) == 'storm')
        {
            $site = $_REQUEST['site'];
        }
```

if so, a better way to code this is:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['site']) && ($_REQUEST['site'] == 'hino' || isset($_REQUEST['site']) == 'storm') {
    $site = $_REQUEST['site'];
}
```

Also:

```
        $Query .= "name             = '".$name."',";
        $Query .= "banner_images    = '".$banner_images."',";
        $Query .= "site     = '".$site."'";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I tried with the second code but still its not working, There is some problem there

Comment: Sorry but I didnt got that. I am reallyy new to this. Sorry for that

Comment: You're missing a comma on the banner_images insert  line.  Look at my solution